# How to subtract 2D data(lots) with 2D data(one) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Hi I am new using MATLAB

What I am going to do is that
I have m-dimensional samples(data), which m is 2 here.

Data in MATLAB code is like this

```
X1 = [4,2;2,4;2,3;3,6;4,4];
X2 = [9,10;6,8;9,5;8,7;10,8];
```

I am going to subtract average of samples, which is

```
Mu1 = [3;3.8];
```

Then can I subtract each 2D data with average of samples in MATLAB code in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to subtract the average `Mu1` from your data (`x1` and `x2`).

If so you could use the bsxfun function:

```
X1_subtracted = bsxfun(@minus, X1, Mu1')
```

which outputs:

```
X1_subtracted =
     1.0000   -1.8000
    -1.0000    0.2000
    -1.0000   -0.8000
          0    2.2000
     1.0000    0.2000
```

Note you are going to have to use `'` with the `Mu1` as `X1` has the shape 5x2 while `Mu1` has the shape 1x2.

Comment: Consider using `.'` instead of `'` to transpose since without the point it would be `ctranspose` not `transpose`. That creates problems when the values are complex since the complex conjugate transpose would be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

To get `X1 - mean(X1)` you could try

```
X = [X1(:,1) - mean(X1(:,1)), X1(:,2) - mean(X1(:,2))]

this will output

    1.  - 1.8  
  - 1.    0.2  
  - 1.  - 0.8  
    0.    2.2  
    1.    0.2
```